# dynamodb scan not working with IN condition

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm failing to get the `IN` condition in my dynamodb scan call to work correctly.

### Background

I'm trying to collect all permissions a user have based on the the roles associated with him, based on this data structure:

```
# Users
| user  | roles 
| admin | ['system-admin', 'basic-user']

# Roles
| role         | permissions
| system-admin | ['MANAGE_USERS', 'DELETE_MODULES']
```

### Code Snippet

```
client.scan(TableName='Roles',
            FilterExpression='#attr IN(:user_roles)',
            ExpressionAttributeNames= {
                '#attr': 'role',
                '#target': 'permissions'
            },
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
              ':user_roles': {'SS': ['system-admin', 'test']}  
            },
            ProjectionExpression='#target')['Items']
```

This scan does not return any items. My expectation would have been:

```
[{'permissions': {'SS': ['DELETE_MODULES', 'MANAGE_USERS']}}]
```

Which I can only achieve by changing the AttributeValues to

```
':user_roles': {'S': 'system-admin'}
```

So am I using the IN condition incorrectly or is it actually not able to take a string set as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly enough I have found that using the boto3 resource API instead of the lower level client it actually works. However I'm still curious what the problem with my original code is.

```
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    roles_table = dynamodb.Table('Roles')
    target_user_permissions = roles_table.scan(
        FilterExpression=Attr('role').is_in(['system-admin', 'test']),
        ExpressionAttributeNames= {
            '#target': 'permissions'
        },
        ProjectionExpression='#target')['Items']
```